# Add an icon to tree view item header

Tags: c#, wpf, treeviewitem

I want to add an image/icon to tree view item on WPF.
How can I do that?
I'm coding a tree view with all my computer files and dir's and I want to make it a little more aesthetic.

I tried:

```
TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem(); 
item.Header = file icon image path;
item.Header += "file";
```

but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class TreeViewSample : Page
    {
        public TreeViewSample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Image tempImage = new Image(); var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/configuration_32x32.png"));
            tempImage.Source = bitmapImage;

            TreeViewItem newItem = new TreeViewItem();
            TextBlock tempTextBlock = new TextBlock();
            tempTextBlock.Inlines.Add(tempImage);
            tempTextBlock.Inlines.Add("SomeText");
            newItem.Header = tempTextBlock;

            MyTreeView1.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
```

[image]